# Order details not displaying (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a strange issue with a site I'm designing. I'm using the WooCommerce system up and running and am using the Wootique theme. I've edited a bit but nothing too major, mostly just colours.

What's happening is, when I go to buy something and checkout, I am able to enter my details but nothing appears under the YOUR ORDER header. The NEXT/CONTINUE button is missing also, so I can't go any further.

Has anyone else experienced this? I can't seem to figure out why it's happening or how to fix it?

The test site is at http://kelvinwinscom.fatcow.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the exact same error on my woocommerce set-up.  In my situation, it was a conflict with jQuery.

Woocommerce loads the latest version of jQuery in your themes head section.  I was manually loading an older version of jQuery in my themes footer.  Having the two copies of jQuery was breaking the "order" section, causing nothing to load.  By removing the jQuery copy I was manually adding, the problem was resolved.

It may be likely that you've done something similar, or that you're using a plugin that is adding jQuery in a non-wordpress manner (Not using wp_enqueue_script and other script registering and enqueue-ing functions)

Comment: this was exactly my issue too. The conflict was caused by the Easing Slider calling JQuery also. I cancelled this call and, like magic, the Order details now appear. Thank you so much for you help, I was completely stumped.